# I reversed polarity on a jump pack when attempting to start my 2000 Dodge Neon.

Tags: battery, ignition

I attempted to jump my 2000 Dodge Neon off in the dark with a jump pack, and I accidentally reversed the polarity. The tire inflator on the jump pack landed on my positive starter wire and burned it in half. The main fuse was also blown. I have replaced both, but my fuel pump is not turning on, and I am getting no current through the starter wires when I turn the ignition. I have tested the starter, and it is working. The engine will turn over if I run a wire directly from the battery to the starter. What are some places I should start looking to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to check all of your fuses and relays under the hood and at the main fuse block, which should be inside the passenger compartment.

Comment: check for fusible links as well, I've seen these fry when a reverse jump goes bad.  http://www.madelectrical.com/electricaltech/images/amp-ga36.jpg

Answer (score 1):

**Starter Solenoid**

If you can turn the starter over when your skip the solenoid then I the logical next step would be to replace your solenoid.

It's a very simple procedure and the solenoid is a relatively inexpensive component

I suggest you swap out your solenoid and see if that resolves your issue.